# ASP.Net MVC model binding - how to change date format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, date-format

I have this application, and the default date format must be `dd/MM/yyyy` (the language is Brazilian Portuguese).

I already had set culture and UI culture to `pt-BR` and now `myDate.ToShortDateString()` returns the dates as I want. I have no trouble displaying them.

The problem is, when the user fills an input field with a date such as `17/08/2011` and submits the form the DateTime parameter to my action becomes null. If I supply a date in the format `08/17/2011`, it works fine.

How can I make the ASP.Net MVC model binding to parse my dates correctly?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528545/mvc-datetime-binding-with-incorrect-date-format/528560#528560

Comment: Try the solution from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177626/asp-net-mvc-default-model-binder-problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found what happended. My form was posting via `GET` method, and the MVC just uses the culture for an action parameter when it's passed in the `RouteData` or by the form via `POST` method.

I just changed the form to `POST` method and it worked.

Comment: A day lost just because noone ever say that the GET method doesn´t apply the culture. Saved my day.. Thanks, still, you should correct your post, it works with POST not with GET.

Comment: More info about how the MVC ModelBinder works and why: http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization

Answer (score 5):

Try this on your property in the view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the issue is a lack of a DateTimeFormat on your DateTime types.

```
<input type="text" name="DateProperty" id="DateProperty"
       value="@(Model.DateProperty.Value.ToString("d",
             System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat))" />
```

EDIT**

Another thing you want to be sure of is that the "name" property of your input element matches what you're passing into your action. If it doesn't null will appear on POST action every time.

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult DoStuff(string dateParam)
     {
       return RedirectToAction("Home","Index", new { });
     }
```

"dateParam" Should match the name property here.

```
<input id="dateParam" name="dateParam" value="10/10/2010" />
```

Comment: Outputting the date to HTML is not the problem. Binding the submitted value is. Even if I do what you said the form submit will not work as expected.