# JQuery DatePicker not updating model field in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datepicker

Following is the code extract:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreatedSearchStartDate, 

            new { @Value=Model.CreatedSearchStartDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),

                @selectedDate =Model.CreatedSearchStartDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),

                @class="dateInput", @id="CreatedSearchStartDate" }

            )
```

Following is relevant JQuery code

```
 $("#CreatedSearchStartDate").each(function () {

    var a = $(this).datepicker(

        {

            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",

            defaultDate: new Date($(this).val())

        })

});
```

The view is showing datepicker control, and it is functioning well. Also, the text box gets updated for underlying value (which I could check using Firebug). The only problem is that the underlying field in the model is not updated. Whereas, there are some other fields also in this model, which gets updated properly.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: can we see the model definition?  Is the textbox inside the form attribute?  why do you use the .each construct to setup only one date picker.  Setting up many would make more sense on the dateInput class like such:  $(".dateInput").each(function () {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling this is a culture problem.  I haven't experienced this problem myself, but I know others have.  If there is a difference between the "culture settings" for your view compared to your application it can cause validation errors.  Also it sounds like you need to make sure you are using post on your form submit for culture to be applied correctly.  Check out these other posts and see if any of them help:

[ASP.Net MVC model binding - how to change date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098613/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-how-to-change-date-format)

[Custom DateTime model binder in Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356601/custom-datetime-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for all your responses and valuable tips.

I have further identified the problem is with the date format. If the date selected is OK as per US format then it successfully gets reflected in model, otherwise it sets null in model.

For example, if user selects "05/01/2013" it gets bind, and if selects "31/01/2013" it sets null.

Any idea what could be the reason?

The date format in datepicker is already set to "dd/mm/yy"

Comment: Make sure you have the [HttpPost] annotation on the controller method that gets called when your form submits.  If that still doesn't work, please post the code from your controller.

Comment: Yes, its there.. The issue was that I was missing setting up culture in web.config. Once I set up Culture and UICulutre, it started working

Comment: great glad you got it working.  You should post what you did as the answer.