# How to customize DateTime format using Editor Templates in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098613/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-how-to-change-date-format)

But i tried that step (I received via POST) and didn't get success.

My globalization setting is `<globalization uiCulture="en-in" culture="en-in"/>`

and Template Code is

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox(
    "",
    Model.HasValue ? @ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue : "",
    new { @class = "date" })
```

And meta data code

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
            ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("Employee Hire Date")]
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
```

and this is the js i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input:text.date").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });
</script>
```

It accepts the Date range as,

```
11/01/2015
7/05/2015
12/04/2015
```

But if i given this

```
    30/04/2015
```

model validation fails.

Couldn't figure out the fix for this.
I started learning MVC as a beginner. So please bear this question. 
Please help me.

**UPDATE**

> ```
> If i change my js code like this
> $(function () {
>         $("input:text.date").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy" });
>     });
> ```
>
> but the format changes to `'30/April/2015'`  which i don't want.

Comment: Do you mean client side validation fails?

Comment: @StephenMuecke after submitting form i got this error ate the side of the textbox says `The field Employee Hire Date must be a date. `

Comment: Do you have `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for the property. Does it actually hit the controller when you click submit?

Comment: No if it gives that error its not hitting controller. For the first three range i mentioned for that it hits controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `jquery.validate.js` validates the date by using the javascript date constructor (`new Date(value)`) which fails. You can use the [jquery globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin or you can override the `jquery.validate` method by adding the following script (assuming this is the jqueryUI datepicker)

```
<script>
  // do NOT wrap in document.ready
  $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
      return true;
    }
    var valid = true;
    try {
      $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
    }
    catch (err) {
      valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
  });
</script>
```

Side notes:

1. `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` is only applicable when using
   `EditorFor()` to generate the browsers implementation of the HTML5
   datepicker (in which case it would need to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}` anyway) so it can be removed.
2. Your template is unnecessary and you should just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HireDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "date" })`

Comment: Thanks for reply..
I added this script in that page and i still get that error

Comment: Make sure you add it after the `jquery.js` and `jquery.validate.js` files and **do not** wrap it in `document.ready()`. And can you confirm you are using the jqueryUI datepicker.

Comment: I added my complete code over there. and if i make alert the value of valid its says true , still i m getting that error

Comment: For testing, replace `@Html.EditorForModel()` with `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HireDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "date" })` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HireDate)`

Comment: I replace and checked.. Bad luck same error comes..
:(

Comment: If `valid` is returning `true` then no error will be displayed (and any existing error message will be removed) so there is something else going on in your code. Are you now hitting the controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75633/discussion-between-shan-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

Stephens Answer is right. Still i modified the script like this to make jquery.validate to work

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", value);
}
```

I guess there is no difference between these two. Still this one is working and this

```
 $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
      return true;
    }
    var valid = true;
    try {
      $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
    }
    catch (err) {
      valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
  });
```

is not working.

Please if some one finds out tel me..
Thanks !!