# Change default DateTime format retrieve from URL parameter ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have URL:

```
http://localhost/Page?id=&created_date=27-09-2017
```

Date format for `created_date` above is "dd-MM-yyyy".

Meanwhile, my controller:

```
public ActionResult Page(string id = null, DateTime? created_date = null)
{
...
}
```

Well, because the URL date format is "dd-MM-yyyy", I cannot retrieve value of `created_date` (still null) in my controller. But if I change the URL date format into "MM-dd-yyyy", `created_date` successfully filled (27 Sept 2017). For example:

```
http://localhost/Page?id=&created_date=09-27-2017
```

How do I change globally this mechanism to "dd-MM-yyyy"? Because there are so many URL patterns like this. I don't want to change the URL date format manually.

--- Update (add custom model binder) ---

Here my `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     var binder = new DateTimeModelBinder("dd-MM-yyyy");
     ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), binder);
     ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), binder);
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
     GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
     FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
     BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

And `DateTimeModelBinder` class:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
     private string _customFormat;

     public DateTimeModelBinder(string customFormat)
     {
         _customFormat = customFormat;
     }

     public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
     {
         var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
         return DateTime.ParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, _customFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725919/how-to-specify-date-format-for-model-binding or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528545/mvc-datetime-binding-with-incorrect-date-format help?

Comment: Writing a custom DateTime binder will work for you, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356601/custom-datetime-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: thanks @mjwills, but still not working after add binder to global.asax

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `BindModel` does it get hit?

Comment: nah, no hit when I start the application or load page @mjwills

Comment: Is that attribute? sorry, I am not sure where to put that because still give me error @mjwills

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154495/discussion-between-andrefadila-and-mjwills).

Comment: any update @andrefadila ?

Comment: forgot about this @JoeLau, better close this one