# DateTime Parsing string to DateTime mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

I've encountered a peculiar issue with my API testing. I'm using a model and have a set of examples for testing purposes:

["abc", "test1", "04/17/1961"]
["def", "test2", "05/23/1995"]
The DateOfBirth is coming through correctly for these cases. However, when I pass in:

["ghi", "test3", "10/12/1994"]
["jkl", "test4", "12/10/1994"]
The DateOfBirth appears as 12/10/1994 for test3 and 10/12/1994 for test4. Strangely, it seems the MM/dd format is getting switched in some instances.

I'm reaching out for assistance in figuring out what might be causing this and how we can parse the string to DateTime without altering the DateTime format.

Here's a snippet of the model I'm working with:

```
[Route("/Some routing", Verbs = "GET")]
public class GetSomeInfo : IReturn<ReturnSomeInfo>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the culture used on the server, or perhaps your machine if that's where you are testing. I'm guessing somewhere outside the US/North America? (E.g., culture of `en-GB` uses DD/MM/YYYY, I believe.) The logic in the parser/model binder is smart enough to know that there's no such thing as a month `17` or `23`, so it flips those to the day for you. My recommendation is to pass around values using the ISO 8601 date time standard, because it's the same everywhere (`YYYY-DD-MM`, and time if you need it). Strings don't get converted to dates, so you'll have to add parsing in later.

Comment: If you want to leave it as a date/datetime on your model, [here's an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725919/how-to-specify-date-format-for-model-binding) that's similar in concept, though the current answer may be different depending on your target version of C# (5+ [core], or .NET Framework [4.x])

Comment: m = Minute, M = Month - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#month-m-format-specifier

Comment: When the culture expects "dd/MM/yyyy" and value is "04/27/2023" parser should throw and not be smart.