# jqueryui datepicker dd/MM/yy culture related issue

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, date-format

I'm using a [**jQueryUI datepicker**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) for a simple "From" & "To" date range filter in my ASP.Net MVC web-app. Works fine until I hit a machine which had its datetime format (in the Regional Settings) set to "dd-MM-yy".

In my controller I've a postback action which accepts a custom search object as a parameter which is then passed to the search function. This custom object has the properties for "To" & "From" dates and as usual the binding takes place automatically. Works normal on a machine with date format "MM/dd/yy" but if I set it to "dd/MM/yy" in the regional settings then it is unable to parse the date.

> The easiest solution could be to change the datepicker's format to
>   "dd-MMM-yyyy" a non-culture specific date format but my client wants
>   the selected date to be displayed in MM/dd/yyyy format.

Any clean and easy suggestion to handle this at the datepicker or controller level?

Comment: Why don't set your properties for "From"/"To" in your custom search object ast strings and convert them yourself in the controller ? You know the format you will receive them (MM/dd/yyyy) so you can convert more easily.

Comment: I was looking for a more standard approach. Hopefully I'm not the only one facing such situations. Something at Model Binder level ?

Comment: Found this pretty interesting [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) about Model Binders. And this [other one](http://dukelupus.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/generic-helper-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding/) and also [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356601/custom-datetime-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an hidden field with a custom format:

HTML:

```
 <input name="from" type="text" id="from" />
 <input name="hiddenFrom" type="hidden" id="hiddenFrom" />
```

Javascript:

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    altField: "#hiddenFrom",
    altFormat: "dd-mm-yy" // or whatever
});
```

You'll find documentation about jquery ui date format [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)

Comment: It's a standard feature of jQuery UI datepicker. Just try it, and use the hidden field value in your backend code.

Comment: My application is a global web site. So how can I make sure its displaying properly in all locations?

ie when my site is opened from US they should see it as mm/dd/yyy (their system's date format)
when its from UK ,format will be dd/mm/yyyy(again depends on their system)

Comment: Please create a new question on stackoverflow for your problem.