# Safe way to pass a date param to an ajax call to a MVC action

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC action that takes one of its parameters a `DateTime` and if I pass "17/07/2012" it throws an exception saying that the param is null but cannot have a null value but if I pass `01/07/2012` it is parsed as `Jan 07 2012`.

I'm passing the dates to the ajax call in `DD/MM/YYYY` format, should I rely on `MM/DD/YYYY` format despite the configured culture in `web.config`?

This is a simple method and there is just this one date parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got three safe options to send date parameter in Asp.NET-MVC:

- Send it as `YYYY/MM/DD` it's the ISO standard for international dates.
- Use `POST` request instead of `GET` request.
- If you want to change the way the default `Model Binder` binds dates:

you can change the default model binder to use the user culture using IModelBinder

```
public class DateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var date = value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        return date;    
    }
}
```

And in the Global.Asax write:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeBinder());
```

Read more at [this excellent blog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8035636/601179) that describe why Mvc framework team implemented a default Culture to all users.

Answer (score 1):

gdoron's answer is correct for passing dates as querystrings.  If they are passed as form values, however (post values) then the correct culture should be used (assuming the culture is property configured).