# Dates from javascript to aspnet core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My page sends a form via $.get to an aspnet core action.

```
$("#submit-form").on("submit", function () {
    var form = $("#submit-form");
    var valuesToSubmit = form.serialize();

    $.get("/MyController/List", valuesToSubmit, function (response) {
        ....
    });     

    return false;
});
```

In this form this is a Date field that is in format: dd/mm/yyyy.
The valuesToSubmit variable has this value:

> Name=&DateBirth=05%2F08%2F1971&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8DHb24pNxPVIkZwi2Mzh0aTz4ZPyAIDsVSVm7-KxVMiV17Z1Twov88zN3F-JwewrGHF9LWSkdp5eOks7KwTgHWRhkdE7N6vfBHeNviCNV1cQdHdW5zPQgk3EEFPN1Lqe0vBK9ay5vnc0oCYWWPPuYgmQTC65iYTy7-0oc0CskGJpul5eSwuS3hUMer4P6g16Ng

I typed `05/08/1971` but in the controller the date parameter comes as `08/05/1971`

My action code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> List(string name, DateTime? dateBirth)
```

Should I change something in the javascript or c# code?

Comment: What's your browser language and what's your windows language?

Comment: This is a known scenario, lots of previous info online if you search about it. If you can, I would either use an unambiguous date format such as yyyy-mm-dd or use a POST request and make sure the server's culture settings would mean that the date format would be understood correctly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10519800/5947043 - it's for asp.net but the same will apply to Core I'm sure

Comment: @ADyson, changing to "post" works.