# Working with dateConversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on creating my own datetimepicker. I want to show the date as by the dateformat. The dateformat includes "MM-dd-yyyy" and other formats.

I wrote the code as below:

```
public DateTime getCurrentDate(string dateFormat)
{            
     curDate = DateTime.Now;            
     IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us", true);
     return DateTime.ParseExact(curDate.ToShortDateString(), dateformat, theCultureInfo); 
}
```

When I execute the program it shows:
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Provide me some solution to handle with error.

Comment: There is a lot of missing data, but this might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356601/custom-datetime-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc/8035636#8035636

Comment: i only want to know about: String not recognized as a valid DateTime. how this error occured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it..
I solve the problem like this..

```
 public string getCurrentDate(string dateFormat)
 {
     curDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
     curDate = String.Format("{0:" + dateFormat + "}", Convert.ToDateTime(curDate));
     return curDate;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ParseExact` Method requires the `format of the string` representation matching the `specified format exactly`. So DateTime.ParseExact(s,format,provider) expects both `s` (specified by provider) and `format` having same format otherwise it throws `String not recognized as a valid DateTime`

In your case dateFormat has to be

```
DateTime y = getCurrentDate("dd/MM/yyyy"); //or
DateTime x = getCurrentDate("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: in my case dateFormat provides the string dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy