# Model attribute validation issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, displayformat

I am formatting `DateTime?` field like `dd/MM/yyyy` and when I submit form it shows validation error.

[image]

I cannot get it why is it happens?

**Model**

```
[Display(Name = "Expected Ending Time")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? ExpectedEndingTime { get; set; }
```

**HTML**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Requsition.ExpectedEndingTime, new { @class = "form-control dataPickerField", id = "ExpectedEndingTimeDataPicker", @readonly = true })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Requsition.ExpectedEndingTime)



<script>
    $(function () {            
        $('#ExpectedEndingTimeDataPicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true           
        })
        .on('changeDate', function (ev) {
              //  do things;
    );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if you input MM/dd/yyyy value, will it work? If yes, then somehow your format doesn't applied

Comment: Can you change ExpectedEndingTime type from DateTime to String and check what value you get from browser?

Comment: Perhaps using a nullable value is causing this issue.

Comment: It also might have something to do with the locale settings in your MVC app. Have you tried to see if `01/15/2014` is valid?

Comment: what DataPicker do you use?

Comment: @Frank59 It is working with String but I need DateTime?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Well I have global setting is  <globalization uiCulture="nb-NO" culture="nb-NO" />

Comment: @Clark Kent, you can simply use DateTime.Parse on this string and check what error will raise. And after that fix it

Comment: When you say it's showing the validation error, is that client-side or is that after it's been POSTed to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was useful for me guys....

So I added 1 extra field to the **Model** and will keep `DateTime` like a `String` in the format I need.

And for places I need `DateTime` format I have another field.

```
[Display(Name = "Expected Ending Time")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? ExpectedEndingTime { get; set; }


[Required]
[Display(Name = "Expected Ending Time")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public string ExpectedEndingTimeAsString { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that DataFormatString is used just for displaying, and it doesn't use by ModelBinder for parsing. So your server still uses Culture from web.config.

You can hardcode specific culture in config that should be used with this date format.

Here is an answer that can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8035636/169635
It has a sample of IModelBinder that uses CurrentCulture for parsing. You can specify own format

Comment: Thanks for the input! I made some investigations but finally I got another solution.