# MVC - Date Format Conversion getting Date as null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date

I am using Jquery ui datepicker, the dateFormat is set to `dd/mm/yyyy`.
My Local machine Server date format is set to `mm/dd/yyyy`. So i converted the format in View.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" value="@string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)" name="LoanDate" required  />
```

In my model on POST, I get `LoanDate` as `null`.

If I reset My Local machine date format to `dd/mm/yyyy`, I get the `LoanDate` in my Controller POST method.

How to solve this Issue?

Comment: you have 2 options, use mm/dd/yyyy formatg in your server, or before post the data convert that date to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: how are you posting the data without a name of the field? I would use javascript to convert on the fly.

Comment: Please check the answer out with 49 (or more) votes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356601/custom-datetime-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: `value=" @DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved it :-

```
public class UTCDateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            // Check if the DateTime property being parsed is not null or "" (for JSONO
            if (value.AttemptedValue != null && value.AttemptedValue != "")
            {
                // Parse the datetime
                var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);                
                return dt;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

In Global.asax - Application_Start() :-

```
var binder = new UTCDateTimeModelBinder();
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), binder);
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), binder);
```

Now i get `LoanDate` Value in my Model in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

http://www.martin-brennan.com/custom-utc-datetime-model-binding-mvc/