# MVC action parameter convert date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I want to store dates in database as Normal Gregorian dates. However, I want to enable user view/edit them in Hijri calendar.

Now I have two problems:

- Before displaying the date, convert it to Hijri (**Done**, using DisplayTemplates)
- After user edit and submit, convert Hijri value to Gregorian. **(My problem)**

I now can use `FormCollection` and invoke a helper method to convert the received Hijri to Gregorian, but I am asking if there is some method to automatically convert the value to Gregorian, maybe something `IModelBinder` ??

Comment: Yes you could use a custom ModelBinder.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you show me how?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of creating a custom model binder for dates (for example some of the [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356601/custom-datetime-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc). Have a go, and if your having problems, post what you have tried.