# Get MinDate When Submit to Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date, knockout.js, momentjs

I'm having a problem when submitting the date to a controller.

The Date is sent in JSON Date format `(ex: /Date(1456592400000)/)`. Then using Knockout custom binding and momentjs, the date is converted into the `'DD/MM/YYYY'` format.

The datepicker is showing the date correctly as `'28/02/2016'`, but when I send it back to the Controller the date value is `'01/01/0001 0:00:00'` which caused the model to be invalid.

Before submitted, I checked the console and the date is `"2016-02-27T17:00:00.000Z"`. But if I don't use Knockout custom binding and just use the value binding, it works.

I try to modify the model binder to format the date, as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356601/custom-datetime-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc), but it still doesn't work.

```
public class DateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, value);

        return value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

I've set the culture id-ID in the web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="id-ID" culture="id-ID" />
```

How do I solve this problem?
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ohp4y4q/) to describe the problem.

Comment: you need time as well at controller end ? way 1) if you need date part just do `split('T')` and send date part .  way 2) in controller make it as string later do a conditional toDateTime conversion . cheers

Answer (score 0):

The time that you see in the console and the one that is sent to server (`2016-02-27T17:00:00.000Z`) is a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation of the selected date converted to UTC.

So in the model binder you need to treat it accordingly:

```
public class DateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    if(value == null)
    {
       return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out date))
    {
       return date.ToLocalTime(); //will convert the dateTime to your local time
    }

    return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

}
```