# ASP.NET MVC parameter is not being received

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Very Simple question...

I have this action on the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? dataini, DateTime? datafim)
        {
            if((dataini != null) && (datafim != null))
            {
                var agendamento = db.agendamento.Where(x => x.data_agendamento >= dataini && x.data_agendamento <= datafim);
                return View(agendamento.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                var agendamento = db.agendamento.Include(a => a.medico).Include(a => a.paciente);
                return View(agendamento.ToList());
            }


        }
```

And this in my view:

```
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "agendamentos", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <b>Data Inicial:</b>@Html.TextBox("dataini", null, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
        <b>Data Final:</b>@Html.TextBox("datafim", null, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
        <input type="submit" value="Filtrar por Data" />
    }
</p>
```

But i'm not receiving the parameter "datafim" from the filter. I'm only receiving the parameter "dataini". What i'm doing wrong ?

UPDATE:
I forgot to put the url being passed:

```
http://localhost:50608/agendamentos/Index?dataini=10%2F05%2F2017+13%3A00&datafim=15%2F12%2F2018+14%3A00
```

UPDATE WITH THE ANSWER:
I just needed to remove the FormMethod.Get of the view and everything worked out. Final code remained the same with this line changed:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "agendamentos"))
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8035636/5071902

Answer (score 1):

> If you see in the URL Date for datafim : 15/12/2018 and your method
>   expecting a date which is formatted as "MM/dd/yyyy", so according to
>   your date 15 is a day but method understands it like a month that's
>   why its been NULL.

Comment: I forgot that i opened this topic, thanks for the answer, but that wasn't the problem...

To solve the problem i just removed the "FormMethod.Get" of this line: @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "agendamentos", FormMethod.Get)) and everything worked out ...